# How are to-many attributes specified in a fetched property?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, core-data, xcode4

I have two entities, Parent and Child. The Parent entity has a to-many relationship to Child named "children." Child has a String attribute named "childName."

I want to make a fetched property on Parent, let's call it "specialChild" that returns a Child with a particular name, let's say "Special". The following predicates return an empty set when I access the fetched property:

- children.childName == "Special"
- SUBQUERY(children, $eachChild, $eachChild.childName =
  "Special").@count > 0
- SUBQUERY(children, $eachChild, ANY $eachChild.childName =
  "Special").@count > 0

I believe I'm messing up the predicate somehow, because I'm still pretty inexperienced with them. (and I can find zero documentation from Apple on "SUBQUERY") How am I supposed to specify "the child whose childName is Special" in the Parent's fetched property predicate?

Yes, I am calling -refreshObject:mergeChanges: but I still receive an empty result. Yes, the destination entity is Child.

[image: visual depiction of data model]

Comment: In the first one, `children.name` or `children.childName`? The predicate needs to use property names that exist on the entity.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I mis-transcribed. It's using the correct property, childName.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is `parent==$FETCH_SOURCE AND childName=="Special"`. This gets any `Child` whose `childName` is "Special" and whose `parent` is the object looking up its special children.

Attributes in a fetched property predicate must exist on the destination entity. Here the destination is `Child`, so you can't use `children` since that only exists on `Parent`.

The `$FETCH_SOURCE` part corresponds to where you'd use `self` if you wrote the predicate in code. Without that you get every special child, not just the ones attached to the originating `Parent`. It says, the `parent` attribute of the child must be the specific instance looking up the fetched property value.

Comment: Awesome. I had tried some permutations of $FETCH_SOURCE, but must have messed up the syntax. Thank you!