# Correct way to accessing attributes of a class modeled in core data

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, core-data

Let's say a `Recipe` object has an `NSSet` of one or more `Ingredient`s, and that the same relationship is modeled in core data.

Given a `recipe`, what id the correct way to access its ingredients?

In this example it seems natural to use `recipe.ingredients`, but I could equally use an `NSFetchRequest` for `Ingredient` entities with an `NSPredicate` to match by recipe.

Now let's say I want only the ingredients that are 'collected'. This is less clear cut to me - should I use a fetch request for ingredients with a predicate restricting by recipe and collected state? Or loop through recipe.ingredients?

At the other end of the scale, perhaps I need only ingredients from this recipe that also appear in other recipes. Now, the fetch request seems more appealing.

What is the correct general approach? Or is it a case by case scenario? I am interested in the impact on:

1. Consitancy
2. Readability
3. Performance
4. Robustness (for example, it is easy to make an error in a fetch request that the compiler cannot catch).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In this example it seems natural to use recipe.ingredients, but I
>   could equally use an NSFetchRequest for Ingredient entities with an
>   NSPredicate to match by recipe.

Why would you do the latter when you can do the former? You already have the recipe, and it already has a set of ingredients, so there's no need to look at *all* the ingredients and filter out just those that are related to the recipe that you already have.

> Now let's say I want only the ingredients that are 'collected'. This
>   is less clear cut to me - should I use a fetch request for ingredients
>   with a predicate restricting by recipe and collected state? Or loop
>   through recipe.ingredients?

Apply the predicate to the recipe's ingredients:

```
NSPredicate *isCollected = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"collected == YES"];
NSSet *collectedIngredients = [recipe.ingredients filteredSetUsingPredicate:isCollected];
```

> At the other end of the scale, perhaps I need only ingredients from
>   this recipe that also appear in other recipes. Now, the fetch request
>   seems more appealing.

Again, using a fetch request here seems wasteful because you already have easy access to the set of ingredients that could be in the final result, and that's potentially a much smaller set than the set of all ingredients. Use the same approach as above, but change the predicate to test the recipes associated with each ingredient. Something like:

```
NSPredicate *p = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"recipes > 1"];
NSSet *i = [recipe.ingredients filteredSetUsingPredicate:p];
```

> What is the correct general approach?

Fetch requests are a good way to search through all instances of a given entity. You're always going to *start* with a fetch request to get some objects to work with. But when the objects you want are somehow related to an object that you already have you can (and should) use those relationships to get what you want.

Comment: if you are not using prefetching, using a predicate to 'in-memory' filter the relationship will fault the object one-by-one, so for a relationship of 100 items, you will have 100 accesses to the store, and very bad performance. you must define prefetching of relationships to avoid this.

Answer (score 1):

Let's go through these in order.

1. Getting the ingredients for a specific `Recipe`, when you already have a reference: Use `recipe.ingredients` every time.
2. Getting the ingredients for a specific `Recipe` that have a specific value (e.g. a Boolean flag value): Easiest is probably to start with `recipe.ingredients` as above and then use something like `NSSet`'s `objectsPassingTest` to filter them. Most elegant is to set up a fetched property on `Recipe` that just returns these ingredients with no extra code (the syntax may not be immediately obvious, see [a previous answer I wrote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14131122/how-are-to-many-attributes-specified-in-a-fetched-property/14149163#14149163) for details). These two probably perform about equally. Least appealing is a fetch request.
3. Getting ingredients that appear in multiple recipe instances: Probably a fetch request for the `Ingredient` entity where the predicate is something like `recipe in %@`, and the `%@` is replaced by a list of `Recipe` instances.

Answer (score 1):

Some basic info:

*memory operations are ~100-1000 times faster then disk operations.
*A fetch request execution is always a trip to the store (disk), and so, degrade performance.

In your case, you have a "small" set of objects that need to be queried for information.
simply iterating over them using the `recipe.ingredients` set **would fault them one by one**, each access will be a trip to the store (fault resolution).

In this case, use prefetching (either in the request, set the `setRelationshipKeyPathsForPrefetching:` to prefetch the `ingredients` relationship or execute a fetch request that fetch the set with the appropriate predicate).

If you need specific data only, then use the fetch request approach to retrieve only the data you need.

if you intend to repeatedly access the relationship for queries and info, just fetch the entire set by using prefetching, and query in-memory.

My point is:

**Think of the approach that minimize your disk access** (in any case you need at least 1 access).
If your data is too large to fit in memory, or to be queried in memory, perform a fetch to get only the data you need.

Now:
1.Consistency - Pick a method you find comfortable and stick with it (i use prefetching)
2.Readability - Using a property is much more readable then executing a query, however it is less efficient if not using prefetching.
3.Performance - Disk access degrade performance, but is unavoidable in some situations
4.Robustness  - A fetch request show that you know what is best for your data usage. use it wisely.

**To make sure you are minimising disk access, turn SQLite debug on**
(-com.apple.CoreData.SQLDebug)

Edit:

[Faulting behaviour](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdPerformance.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003468-SW3)

Comment: Fetch requests do not always involve a trip to the data store. Core Data maintains a row cache of previously fetched data, and fetches are filled from the cache whenever possible.

Comment: Yes they do. try it. I will look for the proof in the documentation. if the returned IDs exist in the row cache then these objects are used as the results, but the fetch reach the disk nonetheless.

Comment: For now I only found this ["Each round trip to the persistent store (each fetch) incurs an overhead ..."](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdPerformance.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003468-SW2)